# How can I send a search query(URL params) using text_field in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

In Task controller (action index) I have this line:

```
@tasks = Task.where("title LIKE '%#{params[:q]}%'")
```

In view I have form_tag like this:

```
= form_tag tasks_path(format: :js), method: :get do |f|
  = text_field_tag :q, params[:q]
  = submit_tag :Search
```

And it is works fine, output in terminal:

```
Started GET "/tasks.js?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=example&commit=Search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-08 10:28:37 +0200
Processing by TasksController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>"example", "commit"=>"Search"}
  Rendering welcome/index.html.haml
  Task Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE (title LIKE '%example%')
```

But I need to use form_for not form_tag.
My form_for form:

```
= form_for tasks_path, method: :get, remote: true do |f|
  = f.text_field :q, value: params[:q]
  = f.submit :Search
```

Terminal output:

```
Started GET "/index?utf8=%E2%9C%93&%2Ftasks%5Bq%5D=fdvdfvdfv&commit=Search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-08 10:30:11 +0200
Processing by WelcomeController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "/tasks"=>{"q"=>"fdvdfvdfv"}, "commit"=>"Search"}
  Rendering welcome/index.html.haml within layouts/application
  Task Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE (title LIKE '%%')
```

And it is don't work, empty between '%%'.
Maybe you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `form_tag` not `form_for`. `form_for` is used to create a form for a model object, which isn't your case.

And to answer your question, when you look at the generated `params` in the log, you have `"/tasks"=>{"q"=>"fdvdfvdfv"}`. so `params[:q]` won't work in this case.

My final answer, go with `form_tag`.

Comment: But form_tag don`t work with option "remote: true". And I need a remote form (not refreshing the page)

Comment: @wannabeaprogrammer It **does work** with `remote: true`. See the docs https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag

Comment: Just to add to this answer, you should look at using placeholders instead of interpolating `params[:q]` directly into your query - this will speed up your query and also safeguard it from SQL Injection. Section 2.2.1 in this guide will help -> https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 5.1+ you should use `form_with` which replaces both `form_for` and `form_tag`.

### Without a model

```
= form_with(url: tasks_path(format: :js), method: :get) do |f|
  = f.text_field :q, value: params[:q]
  = f.submit :Search
```

Make sure you parameterize the SQL query to avoid a SQL injection vulnerability:

```
@tasks = Task.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
```

### Virtual model

Or you can create a virtual model, which is a model without a database table:

```
# app/models/seach_query.rb
class SearchQuery
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :q
end
```

---

```
= form_with(model: (@search_query || SearchQuery.new) url: tasks_path(format: :js), method: :get) do |f|
  = f.text_field :q
  = f.submit :Search
```

---

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
    if params[:search_query]
      @search_query = SearchQuery.new(params.fetch(:search_query).permit(:q))
      @tasks = @tasks.where('tasks.title LIKE ?', "%#{ @search_query.q }%")
    end
  end
end
```

The advantage of a virtual model is that you can use validations, localize fields with the I18n module etc and organize your code.